# Adjusting caption below single post image

Tags: images

First of all, I have to apologize, my php-skills aren't good enough to solve this myself. So I hope that someone will kindly help me in this matter.

I'm trying to adjust the image caption below single post images. Instead of displaying the caption (post_excerpt), I would like to display the image title (post_title) and image description (post_content).
I somewhat got what I'm looking for with the following code:

```
add_shortcode('wp_caption', 'img_caption_add_description');
add_shortcode('caption', 'img_caption_add_description');
function img_caption_add_description($attr, $content = null)
{
$post_id = str_replace('attachment_', '', $attr['id']);
$img = get_post((int)$post_id);

if (is_a($img, 'WP_Post')) {
    $image_title = $img->post_title;
    $image_content = $img->post_content;
    $attr['caption'] = '<span class="title-css">' . $image_title . '</span><br><span class="description-css">' . $image_content . '</span>';
}

return img_caption_shortcode($attr, $content);
}
```

Obviously, title and description are only added to the caption as shown here:
[image: Screenshot]

How can I replace the caption with the image title and description, thus only showing title and description?

My caption shortcode in the editor looks like this:

```
[caption id="attachment_214" align="alignleft" width="999"]
<img class="size-full wp-image-214"
    src="https://www.[...]/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/geierlay-2.jpg"
    alt="Alt Geierlay" width="999" height="749" />
 Bechriftung Test[/caption]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Override The Image Caption With Image Title And Description

Here's a way to override the caption with the image title and image description, with a demo plugin.

Let's assume we have uploaded this image:

[image: espresso]

Then we insert it into the editor with the following:

```
[caption id="attachment_123" align="aligncenter" width="300"]
  <a href="https://example.tld/2017/03/01/hello-world/espresso/"    
       rel="attachment wp-att-123">
    <img src="https://example.tld/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/espresso-300x180.jpg" 
         alt="" width="300" height="180" class="size-medium wp-image-123" />        
   </a> espresso caption
[/caption]
```

**Before:**

Without our plugin activated it will display as:

[image: before]

**After:**

With the plugin activated it displays:

[image: after]

Hope it helps!

### Demo plugin:

We use the filters `img_caption_shortcode` and `shortcode_atts_caption`.

Here we wrap it into a class to pass on the attachment id between the filter callbacks.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Modified Image Caption
 * Description: Override The Image Caption With Image Title And Description
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/258612/26350
 */

namespace WPSE\Q258586;

add_action( 'init', [ new Caption, 'init' ] );

class Caption
{
    private $attachment_id ;

    public function init()
    {
        add_filter( 'img_caption_shortcode',    [ $this, 'shortcode' ], 999, 3 );
        add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_caption',   [ $this, 'atts' ],      999, 3 );
    }
    public function shortcode( $output, $attr, $content )
    {
        if( isset( $attr['id'] ) && preg_match( '/attachment_\d+/i', $attr['id' ] ) )
            $this->attachment_id = str_replace( 'attachment_', '', $attr['id'] );

        return $output;
    }

    public function atts( $atts, $pair )
    {
        if( ! $this->attachment_id  )
            return $atts;

        $img = get_post( $this->attachment_id );

        if( is_a( $img, '\WP_Post' ) )
        {
            $atts['caption'] = sprintf( 
                '<span class="title-css">%s</span>
                 <br><span class="description-css">%s</span>',
                esc_html( $img->post_title ),
                esc_html( $img->post_content )
            );
        }

        $this->id = null;

        return $atts;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I created the plugin with your code snippet, activated it and created a new post to test it. Unfortunately, there seems to be no effect. Only the caption is displayed. ("<figcaption class="caption wp-caption-text">Bechriftung Test</figcaption>")

Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you inserting the image into the editor? What's the code there? @HansWernersen

Comment: I am inserting the image via the regular Wordpress "Add Media" button, as shown here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Inserting_Media_into_Posts_and_Pages

Comment: I updated the answer with an example how it shows up on my install @HansWernersen

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my original post to show my caption shortcode in the editor. I don't know why, but it looks different from yours. Could that be the reason why the plugin shows no effect for me?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference if the image is linked or not. I'm not sure why it's not having any effect on your install. I tested this on a vanilla install. You should try to debug it and check the various values wihtin the plugin, just in case.

Comment: I just switched to the standard "Twenty Sixteen" theme and your plugin is definitely working. I am using the "Activello" theme however, and here, the plugin shows no effect. Could you please point me in the right direction to get your plugin working while using the Activello theme?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out myself. In Activello's extras.php there is a "activello_caption" function that is also making use of the "img_caption_shortcode" filter, thus disabling your plugin. I disabled "activello_caption" via "remove_action" and emulated the Activello border styling via css. Now everything's perfect. Thank you very much for your quick and perfect help!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear it worked. I adjusted the filter priority. @HansWernersen

Comment: Sorry @birgire to bother you again: while your solution absolutely works as asked, I would like to make a small change to it and don't quite know how.  Essentially, I would like to be able to make individual changes to the caption that is displayed when necessary (by editing the image information within the visual editor). I described this further in the following thread: [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/260291) It would be great if you could point me to the right direction to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.